# Is it possible to mock a nested object that is accessed by reflection?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I need to mock an instance of `RestRequest` with `Mockito` in a way that this method would return for example `10.0.0.1`.

```
private static String getAddress(RestChannel channel) {
    String remoteHost = null;

    try {
        NettyHttpChannel obj = (NettyHttpChannel) channel;
        Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("channel");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) f.get(obj);
        InetSocketAddress remoteHostAddr = sc.getRemoteAddress();
        remoteHost = remoteHostAddr.getAddress().getHostAddress();
        // Make sure we recognize localhost even when IPV6 is involved
        if (localhostRe.matcher(remoteHost).find()) {
            remoteHost = LOCALHOST;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return remoteHost;
}
```

Is this something **feasible at all**? I'd need to mock at least until the call to `SocketChannel.getRemoteAddress()`, where the socket channel is a private field accessed by reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [this](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/1.3.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/http/netty/NettyHttpChannel.html) is your `NettyHttpChannel` and channel is a field for `org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel`

You could use the constructor:

```
NettyHttpChannel(NettyHttpServerTransport transport, 
     org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel channel, NettyHttpRequest request)
```

with a mocked [`SocketChannel`](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/Channel.html):

```
NettyHttpServerTransport nettyHttpServerTransport = Mockito.mock(NettyHttpServerTransport.class);
NettyHttpRequest NettyHttpRequest = Mockito.mock(nettyHttpRequest.class);
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = Mockito.mock(InetSocketAddress.class);
SocketChannel channel = Mockito.mock(SocketChannel.class);
Mockito.when(channel.getRemoteAddress()).thenReturn(inetSocketAddress);
NettyHttpChannel nettyHttpChannel = new NettyHttpChannel(nettyHttpServerTransport, channel, request);
// ...
// call getAddress(nettyHttpChannel) 
// ...
```

That should work

Comment: there's a few typos in your answer, and the `NettyHttpChannel` constructor has changed, but I ended up making it work your way because mockito CANNOT MOCK `Field` types.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Mockito does not support mocking types like `Field`, so directly mocking the reflection stuff would not cut it (as I feared).
So I ended up following the suggestion of @RC. But with a few changes:

```
NettyHttpServerTransport nettyHttpServerTransport = mock(NettyHttpServerTransport.class);
NettyHttpRequest nettyHttpRequest = mock(NettyHttpRequest.class);
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, 80);
SocketChannel channel = mock(SocketChannel.class);
when(nettyHttpRequest.getChannel()).thenReturn(channel);
when(channel.getRemoteAddress()).thenReturn(inetSocketAddress);
NettyHttpChannel c = new NettyHttpChannel(nettyHttpServerTransport, nettyHttpRequest, null, true);
```